# How do I determine what dependency versions to require in a package?

Tags: python, setuptools

For the install_requires option of setuptools.setup, one can specify a minimum version of a required package:

```
setup(
    name="mypackage",
    ...
    install_requires = ["somedep>=x.y.z"]
)
```

How do I determine the appropriate value of x.y.z, without in-depth knowledge of the feature history of `somedep`?

(context: from the user/admin perspective, I have run into cases where a minimum version was required but not specified, making for very strange errors. I would like to not cause that problem for anyone else.)